# Using Apache-Commons-net to add a self signed SSL certificate

Tags: java, ssl, apache-commons-net, ftps

I'm using Apache Commons Net FTPSClient to build a FTPS plugin for my web application. A user can use my application and connect to his/her FTPS server and pull files into my application which does some functionality with those files. 
If the user is using a self-signed certificate, I am reading that Java causes issues which can be resolved in a few ways as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056173/java-ftps-connection-trustmanager-explaination-using-filezilla-server) by @dave_thompson_085. I cannot change my JRE trustStore since my application is hosted on servers that I don't have access to. The last option - "code your own truststore. Create a java.security.KeyStore and load it with data containing your cert, then create a real javax.net.ssl.TrustManager and .init it with your keystore; then use that TrustManager in your SSLContext."
I'm not sure I understand what this means. Does this again involve changing the keystore and require JRE to pick up these changes? 
Also, is there an explicit method in the library to add a certificate file? Where do I add the certificate file for Java or the library to verify in the first place.

Comment: @Kenster, sorry about that. I'm using Apache Commons Net. I've editted my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, no, your not editing the cacerts file directly via command line or keytool or anything like that.  This method refers to creating an object instance of KeyStore or JKS, so JRE doesn't pickup any changes you're doing this within the code and then using the a trust manager init'd with the keystore you've created to connect via SSL.  Loosely speaking, you're overriding the default keystore which is the cacerts file, programmatically in order to avoid changing the flat file outright.

There are explicit methods to add files to Keystores.

Add the cert to the KeyStore instance.

You might want to checkout BouncyCastle's library.  Its really, really great for what you're trying to do.  Maybe even a little overkill but really great.

Comment: did you mean using BouncyCastle's library to verify an SSL certificate for an FTPS Connection?

Comment: If you want to verify an ssl certificate chain you can also use Bouncey Castle's library tho.

Comment: is it necessary to add the cert file to the Keystore even if it is a valid CA  certificate? I don't see a method that Apache Commons net provides to add a cert file. How does Java know that it is not a self-signed certificate and accept it if I don't add it to the Keystore?

Comment: A keystore is just a container, there's a chain that must be 'built' for trust which you can do by importing the certificates into the keystore programmatically or via command line w/ keytool.  There's a concept of naivety when validity comes into play. For actual validation with a library like Bouncey Castle, you will need to validate against a set of trusted root and intermediate certs.

Comment: You're referring to 'The Keystore' as if there's only one, but you can create instances of them really easily within your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the cert file to the cacerts file using keytool.  The cacerts file is located in the same place as the installed JRE.  For example:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\security
```

Keystore command could be something like:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias your_alias -file cert.crt -keystore cacerts
```

Default password is "changeit"